# Cannot connect to ssh-agent with automation script in Linux

Tags: linux, authentication, ssh

I'm trying to write a script to automate an `rclone` process that requires ssh authentication via public key with a passphrase for the private key. The authentication service does not run by default in a new session. Manually I can do

```
$ eval `ssh-agent`
Agent pid 2335
$ ssh-add
Enter passphrase for /home/user/.ssh/private_key:
Identity added: /home/user/.ssh/private_key (/home/user/.ssh/private_key)
```

and then I run the `rclone` process. However, if I run the script, let's call it `auth`

```
#!/bin/bash
eval `ssh-agent`
/path/to/scpw
```

where `scpw` is an `expect` script that automates the passphrase input for `ssh-add`, then I get the same output as manual entry:

```
$ /path/to/auth
Agent pid 2335
Enter passphrase for /home/user/.ssh/private_key:
Identity added: /home/user/.ssh/private_key (/home/user/.ssh/private_key)
```

but when I try to run the `rclone` process now, I get the error message

```
yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss Failed to create file system for "computer:directory": couldn't 
connect to ssh-agent: SSH agent requested but SSH_AUTH_SOCK not-specified
```

which is the same error message I get if I didn't run `ssh-add` at all. I tried several variants such as

```
eval `ssh-agent` && ssh-add
eval `ssh-agent` && sleep 3 && ssh-add`
eval `ssh-agent` && /path/to/scpw (where scpw waits 3 seconds to enter passphrase)
```

all of which also worked manually but didn't work in script. I'm pretty baffled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different issues ([here](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/1172) or [there](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/884)) point out to the lack of the private key.

In your case, check if:

- this would work better with a default name key (for testing) id_rsa
- if the `expect` script spawns a subshell (in which the private key is added to the agent) but, on the next line, the `rclone` command would not benefit from that, because the agent is only populated by the `scpw` `expect` script in a subshell.

Answer (score 1):

You should not `eval ssh-agent` multiple times, that would create multiple instances of ssh-agent.

What you need is

```
nohup ssh-agent 2>/dev/null | grep -v echo > $HOME/.ssh/sh.pid
ssh-add
```

and then in your scripts which need ssh-agent, do :

```
source $HOME/.ssh/sh.pid
```